# Jenkins - Changing the Default Path and Name of Build.xml

Tags: jenkins, ant, continuous-integration

I'm trying to configure a job that runs with Ant on Jenkins.
I was wonder if there is an option to change the path of the build.xml file
(that it will not run from  /var/lib/jenkins/jobs//workspace/)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set -Dbasedir=/do/start/here in java options or system properties in the job configuration